# EC2 Instance Store to EBS Can't connect to SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I followed every line on this tutorial:
http://webkist.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/creating-an-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-from-a-running-instance/
to create a EBS instance using a AMI based on a Instance Store snapshot

However my new EBS instance cannot be connected through SSH (Timeout error).

The console outputs the following:

> Linux version 2.6.16-xenU (root@ip-10-204-118-8) (gcc version 4.0.2
>   20051125 (Red Hat 4.0.2-8)) #14 SMP Wed Nov 23 08:48:06 EST 2011
>
> BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
>
> Xen: 0000000000000000 - 000000006d400000 (usable)
>
> 1020MB HIGHMEM available.
>
> 727MB LOWMEM available.
>
> NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
>
> Built 1 zonelists
>
> Kernel command line: root=/dev/sdf ro 4
>
> Enabling fast FPU save and restore... done.
>
> Enabling unmasked SIMD FPU exception support... done.
>
> Initializing CPU#0
>
> PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 65536 bytes)
>
> Xen reported: 2133.408 MHz processor.
>
> Console: colour dummy device 80x25
>
> Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>
> Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
>
> Software IO TLB disabled
>
> vmalloc area: ee000000-f53fe000, maxmem 2d7fe000
>
> Memory: 1759232k/1789952k available (1970k kernel code, 21364k
>   reserved, 628k data, 156k init, 1044488k highmem)
>
> Checking if this processor honours the WP bit even in supervisor
>   mode... Ok.
>
> Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 4267.73 BogoMIPS
>   (lpj=21338685)
>
> Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
>
> CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
>
> CPU: L2 cache: 256K
>
> CPU: L3 cache: 4096K
>
> Checking 'hlt' instruction... OK.
>
> Brought up 1 CPUs
>
> migration_cost=0
>
> Grant table initialized
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 16
>
> Enabling SMP...
>
> Initializing CPU#1
>
> migration_cost=102
>
> Brought up 2 CPUs
>
> xen_mem: Initialising balloon driver.
>
> highmem bounce pool size: 64 pages
>
> VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.1
>
> Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> Initializing Cryptographic API
>
> io scheduler noop registered
>
> io scheduler anticipatory registered (default)
>
> io scheduler deadline registered
>
> io scheduler cfq registered
>
> i8042.c: No controller found.
>
> RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 4096K size 1024 blocksize
>
> Xen virtual console successfully installed as tty1
>
> Event-channel device installed.
>
> netfront: Initialising virtual ethernet driver.
>
> mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
>
> md: md driver 0.90.3 MAX_MD_DEVS=256, MD_SB_DISKS=27
>
> md: bitmap version 4.39
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 2
>
> Registering block device major 8
>
> sdf: unknown partition table
>
> netfront: device eth0 has copying receive path.
>
> IP route cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
>
> TCP established hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
>
> TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>
> TCP: Hash tables configured (established 262144 bind 65536)
>
> TCP reno registered
>
> TCP bic registered
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 1
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 17
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 15
>
> Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
>
> XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
>
> md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
>
> md: autorun ...
>
> md: ... autorun DONE.
>
> kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
>
> EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
>
> VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly.
>
> Freeing unused kernel memory: 156k freed
>
> lxcmount stop/pre-start, process 676 libudev:
>   udev_monitor_new_from_netlink_fd: error getting socket: Invalid
>   argument mountall:mountall.c:3666: Assertion failed in main:
>   udev_monitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink (udev, "udev") General
>   error mounting filesystems. A maintenance shell will now be started.
>   CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system. Give root
>   password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

What are the possible causes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with ssh because ssh never starts up due to the error you can see at the end of the log:

> lxcmount stop/pre-start, process 676 libudev:
>   udev_monitor_new_from_netlink_fd: error getting socket: Invalid
>   argument mountall:mountall.c:3666: Assertion failed in main:
>   udev_monitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink (udev, "udev") General
>   error mounting filesystems. A maintenance shell will now be started.
>   CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system. Give root
>   password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

So either you made a mistake following the instructions in the blog post or the instructions no longer work for some reason.

You're probably better off re-creating your instance using a tool like [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) to manage it rather than just making a wholesale copy of an image; that is certainly a better long-term solution.