# EC2 Instance Store to EBS Can't connect to SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EC2 Instance Store to EBS Can't connect to SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/352307/ec2-instance-store-to-ebs-cant-connect-to-ssh)

I followed every line on this tutorial:
http://webkist.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/creating-an-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-from-a-running-instance/
to create a EBS instance using a AMI based on a Instance Store snapshot

However my new EBS instance cannot be connected through SSH (Timeout error).

The console outputs the following:

> Linux version 2.6.16-xenU (root@ip-10-204-118-8) (gcc version 4.0.2
>   20051125 (Red Hat 4.0.2-8)) #14 SMP Wed Nov 23 08:48:06 EST 2011
>
> BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
>
> Xen: 0000000000000000 - 000000006d400000 (usable)
>
> 1020MB HIGHMEM available.
>
> 727MB LOWMEM available.
>
> NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
>
> Built 1 zonelists
>
> Kernel command line: root=/dev/sdf ro 4
>
> Enabling fast FPU save and restore... done.
>
> Enabling unmasked SIMD FPU exception support... done.
>
> Initializing CPU#0
>
> PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 65536 bytes)
>
> Xen reported: 2133.408 MHz processor.
>
> Console: colour dummy device 80x25
>
> Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>
> Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
>
> Software IO TLB disabled
>
> vmalloc area: ee000000-f53fe000, maxmem 2d7fe000
>
> Memory: 1759232k/1789952k available (1970k kernel code, 21364k
>   reserved, 628k data, 156k init, 1044488k highmem)
>
> Checking if this processor honours the WP bit even in supervisor
>   mode... Ok.
>
> Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 4267.73 BogoMIPS
>   (lpj=21338685)
>
> Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
>
> CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
>
> CPU: L2 cache: 256K
>
> CPU: L3 cache: 4096K
>
> Checking 'hlt' instruction... OK.
>
> Brought up 1 CPUs
>
> migration_cost=0
>
> Grant table initialized
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 16
>
> Enabling SMP...
>
> Initializing CPU#1
>
> migration_cost=102
>
> Brought up 2 CPUs
>
> xen_mem: Initialising balloon driver.
>
> highmem bounce pool size: 64 pages
>
> VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.1
>
> Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
>
> Initializing Cryptographic API
>
> io scheduler noop registered
>
> io scheduler anticipatory registered (default)
>
> io scheduler deadline registered
>
> io scheduler cfq registered
>
> i8042.c: No controller found.
>
> RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 4096K size 1024 blocksize
>
> Xen virtual console successfully installed as tty1
>
> Event-channel device installed.
>
> netfront: Initialising virtual ethernet driver.
>
> mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
>
> md: md driver 0.90.3 MAX_MD_DEVS=256, MD_SB_DISKS=27
>
> md: bitmap version 4.39
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 2
>
> Registering block device major 8
>
> sdf: unknown partition table
>
> netfront: device eth0 has copying receive path.
>
> IP route cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
>
> TCP established hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
>
> TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>
> TCP: Hash tables configured (established 262144 bind 65536)
>
> TCP reno registered
>
> TCP bic registered
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 1
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 17
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 15
>
> Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
>
> XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
>
> md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
>
> md: autorun ...
>
> md: ... autorun DONE.
>
> kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
>
> EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
>
> VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly.
>
> Freeing unused kernel memory: 156k freed
>
> lxcmount stop/pre-start, process 676 libudev:
>   udev_monitor_new_from_netlink_fd: error getting socket: Invalid
>   argument mountall:mountall.c:3666: Assertion failed in main:
>   udev_monitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink (udev, "udev") General
>   error mounting filesystems. A maintenance shell will now be started.
>   CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system. Give root
>   password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

I wonder what the possible causes are.

Comment: better on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

The ssh timeouts because the instance hasn't even booted. You first have to get that instance running to connect with SSH; look at the status checks and see that your instance hasn't passed them. 
Second problem: your instance doesn't start because there's an error with the filesystem. Yesterday I tried to do something similar to what you are trying to do and corrected this issue by manually entering the same kernel id the previous instance had in the new one (when you launch the new instance through the wizard).